# Angular4 Ng2ModalWindow

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I have used Ng2ModalWindow to display the modal popup in my project.

I have displayed a component(*editComponent*) using '*componentSelector*' inside the modal. I have a button labeled "update" in the *editComponent*.

On the update button click, I want the data from the *editcomponent* to be passed to the component from where I have opened the window.

How can this be achieved?

Sample:

Parent component:

```
Ng2ModalWindow.showModal(this.modalId, {
      title: 'Modal',
      customClass: 'modal-lg',
      overlayClick: false,
      componentSelector: 'editComponent'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Ng2ModalWindow docs, you can pass a list of inputs to the component referenced in `componentSelector`, using the property `componentInputs`.

So, you could pass a callback on the parent component like:

```
Ng2ModalWindow.showModal(this.modalId, { 
    ..., 
    componentSelector: 'editComponent', 
    componentInputs: {
        onEdited: (data) => { ... }
    }
});
```

Note that `onEdited`, in this case, needs to be a public property on editComponent.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal-module#usage

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I am able to pass the values from my parent to the componentSelector.But not viceversa.Is any plunker example available?